# Change title of Keycloak login

Tags: html, authentication, keycloak

I want to know how to change title on login page via `Keycloak`?

[image]

Comment: Using https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#creating-a-theme

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to change the following line in `themes/base/login/messages/messages_[your_language].properties`.

```
loginTitle=Log in to {0}
```

However, I suggest you should read [the official document](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes) and create your original theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to themes[your theme]\login\resources\css\login.css

You can add like this

```
/* Title */
#kc-page-title::after {
    content: " to MyHomeLogin"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following if you are working with a custom theme.

1. Go to **themes/base/login**.
2. Copy the file **template.ftl**
3. Go to **themes/custom/login** -> 'custom' or the name of your theme
4. Paste the **template.ftl** file there
5. Open **template.ftl**
6. Search for the  element
7. Replace the content with your desired text
8. Save it and reload the page

[image]

I prefer this method because it only overwrites the base theme at runtime without making any changes to the base theme directly. Thanks.